# Screen buffer is corrupted when resuming from suspend in Xubuntu

Tags: external-display, xubuntu, suspend

I have a ThinkPad x220 and Xubuntu 11.04. At work I use an external 22" monitor with a VGA cable.

When my day is over, I tell Xubuntu to disconnect from the monitor and only use the laptop monitor. I then disconnect the cable and close the lid to suspend. When I resume from suspend after this procedure, the screen buffer is corrupted, and I cannot do anything. The mouse cursor moves so it doesn't seem like a total crash.

Note that this does not happen when I don't connect the 22" monitor i.e. "regular" suspend works.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: what happens if you disconnect the monitor, reboot the computer, then suspend?  Which is what you might have already inferred?

Comment: In that case it works.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the corruption? I am thinking of 2 things, 1) on comming out of GPU standby the driver still uses the buffer wrongly (a driver problem) display is comming out of buffer going to wrong places . 2) the screen memory is being refreshed during standby (wrongly) and overheat of the video rams (could be tested by being in alaska :-) or testing power consumption. I dont know laptops or linux well enough, but both could be a driver/standby/reset thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue. I work with a Thinkpad X220 and have Xubuntu 11.10 installed.

When I suspend my laptop, while connected to my external monitor (either cloned or only using the external monitor), it gives a blank screen when coming out of suspend. I can still see my mouse moving, but both screens remain blank.

Some further information;

A)
I have memorized the "Display settings" command. When I press the command sequence on my keyboard to 1) show only laptop screen and then 2) show only the external screen, my display (on the external monitor) returns and I can proceed as normal. But I have to do this every time, and when I make one mistake I am lost (as I cannot see the output unless I do it completely right).

B)
I have now enabled a dual-monitor setting, using the command 
"xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of LVDS1".
Now, when I put my laptop to sleep/suspend, both displays work normally (dual) after resuming from sleep or suspend. But I do not use the display configuration then, just this command with xrandr.

I am not an expert, so I do not exactly know what the problem/solution might be. But I guess I am looking in the right direction.

Comment: The solution I ended up with was switching to Linux Mint. I really got tired of Xubuntu and all of its shortcomings. Mint just works :)